# How to start using rajawali vr

Tags: android, android-studio, rajawali, rajawalivr

I'm using Android Studio. I want to use Rajawali library, especially the vr package. I add the following line to build.gradle as described in GitHub.

```
compile 'org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.0.325@aar'
```

Then I am able to use some classes in Rajawali library, such as `RajawaliRenderer`. But when I import package `org.rajawali3d.vr`, Android Studio says " Cannot resolve symbol 'vr' ". What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: download git source and use it if aar file is not working then.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solve it. Adding the line below into `build.gradle` only imports `rajawali` package into your project.

```
compile 'org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.0.325@aar'
```

The other sub-packages like `VR`, `Vuforia` are not imported, so you need to do it manually.

Follow the steps below:

1. Go to https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali and download the entire
   library.
2. Go to `Rajawali-master\vr\src\main\java\org\rajawali3d`. Copy the `vr` folder into your project.
3. Go to `Rajawali-master\vr\libs`. Copy `audio.jar` and `cardboard.jar` to `app\libs` in your project.
4. Select the two jar files, right click and choose "Add as Library...".
5. Done.

Note that you still have to add `rajawali` dependency in `build.gradle` first.

Comment: Copy `vr` folder to where in the project hierarchy?

Comment: is it possible to convert 2d images to 3d using rajawali